# JPA2: how to persist data using @MapKeyColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, jpa-2.0

In my example I have two entities to persist. But when I try to using @MapKeyColumn annotation , I am confused on how to use this annotation and how to persist the data. This is the example that is explained in the "PRO JPA2 book". When I try to run this code it will generate the exception.

two entities:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name; 
private String salary;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EmployeeType type;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="dept_id")
private Department deparment;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Department {
@Id 
@Column(name="dept_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String Name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="deparment")
@MapKeyColumn(name="cabin_id")
private Map<String , Employee> empCabin;
    ......................................
   public Map<String, Employee> getEmpCabin() {
    return empCabin;
}

public void assignEmpToCabin(Employee emp , String cabinNo) {
    System.out.println(emp+"   "+cabinNo);
    getEmpCabin().put(cabinNo, emp);

    if(emp.getDeparment() != null){
        emp.getDeparment().removeEmpFromDept(emp);
    }

    emp.setDeparment(this);
}

public void removeEmpFromDept(Employee emp) {
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Employee>> entrySet = getEmpCabin().entrySet().iterator();
    if(entrySet.hasNext()){
        Employee current = ((Map.Entry<String, Employee>) entrySet.next()).getValue();
        if(current.getId() == emp.getId()){
            System.out.println("dept remove");
            entrySet.remove();
            current.setDeparment(null);
        }
    }
}
```

my service class function

```
public class EmployeeService {
private EntityManager em;
.............
public void setEmpCabin(Employee emp , Department dept , String cab_id) {
    dept.assignEmpToCabin(emp, cab_id);
}
```

My main code :

```
tr.begin();
        Department dept = deps.createDepartment("Sci");
        Employee emp = es.createEmployee("Harmeet Singh", "500" , "5684", dept);
        es.setEmpCabin(emp, dept, "10");
tr.commit();
```

when i try to insert the data using setEmpCabin(...) function , it wil generate the exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Field 'cabin_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: I suspect you have defined the cabin_id column as `not null`, without a default value. And your code creates an employee without a cabin_id, so the database doesn't know what to store in this field.

Comment: so , waht is the correct way to store the data. please explain with code.

Comment: I don't have much experience with maps in mappings. But start by removing the not null constraint and see if it makes a difference. You could also map the cabin_id column as a field in Employee, and use the MapKey annotation.

Comment: when i remove the not null from employee table , the value of cabin_id is null.

Comment: I'm not sure you can use this annotation if the association is bidirectional (and thus mapped by the other side). Try mapping the cabin_id column, and using the MapKey annotation.

Comment: this example is available in pro jpa2 book .

Comment: You could try @MapKeyColumn(name="cabin_id", nullable=false) if that doesn't help switch on SQL logging to see what SQL is generated and also provide the table definitions.

Comment: if the `nullable=false` the query execute successfully , but the value of column is null. according to this example the predicted value is 10.

Comment: when i try to use `@MapKey` annotation the program is run and there is no need to add element in the Map , But what is the problem with `@MapKeyColumn` annotation.